# Ip address DNS and Domains

Tags: networking, dns, ip

I'm a little confused about IP addresses.

I know that every web domain has an ip address. 
Does the IP address represent the physical machine / host the website files are stored on?

Therefore when DNS lookup is performed, the domain's IP address is returned to the client. The client then uses this ip to contact the server that the web files reside on.

Is my understanding correct?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

It is kind of like how some companies may say Dial PIZZAHUT instead of saying, Dial 74992488. PIZZAHUT is easier to remember, but you actually are dialling the number.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about HTTP protocol. Yes, FQDN (web domain) is resolved to IP address by DNS server. Client will connect to server IP address. Since you're probably using HTTP 1.1, HTTP request will contain also FQDN. This information is used by web server to perform several checks, like SSL certificate validation or Virtualhost management (several domains on a single IP address).

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. If we have a sub domain, this means - contact the  server represented by the domains ip and then a computer that resides on that network? In short, we are navigating one level deeper

Comment: No. Third level domains can be anywhere. Consider test.example.com and home.example.com. They are different FQDNs and DNS can resolve them to completely different IP addresses. No hierarchy here.